# How to get mount point for a given path in custom linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, mount-point

As the title says I have a problem with my custom kernel module. My goal is to retrieve the root mount point of a given path. Just like using df:

```
df "/tmp/some_dir/some_file"
vvvvvvvv out vvvvvvvv
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on <---
tmpfs            8125932   120   8125812   1% /tmp <----
```

I was trying to achieve it with path struct by using both mnt and dentry fields but when I printed mnt_root or superblock root it always returned '/' so not associated mounting point.

Maybe I'm just digging in the wrong place. I don't know if path/dentry/etc... are suitable structures for these operations (I'm beginning my adventure with kernel modules and probably I'm overkilling it :D)

**Kernel version**: 5.6.2

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Which kernel version are you on? That'd be a useful information, add it to the question.

Comment: You're right I totally forgot about this. I'm on 5.6.2 right now

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to reach my goal!

It turns out that there is [follow_up](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namei.c#L1183) function in namei.c which does exactly what I needed.